# How to make TabNavigator's indicator width consistent with label text width in React-Navigation?

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator

As the title saying,How can we make TabNavigator's indicator width consistent with label text width in React-Navigation? Any solutions?

Comment: have the exact same problem, have you find any solution yet ?

Comment: @ Charas Nope! You?